# Is pasting "javascript:alert('hi')" in the address bar blocked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, progressive-web-apps, address-bar

You can type this into the address bar in Google Chrome and it works:

```
javascript:alert('hi');
```

However if you try to paste the same string into the adress bar you just get this:

```
alert('hi');
```

Is that by design? Or? Standards? Security?

(I am trying to find an easier way to use bookmarklets on mobile phones. Needed for a PWA.)

Comment: `javascript:` tells the browser that you're passing javascript. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes#Unofficial_but_common_URI_schemes and https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03

Comment: it's b/c of security

Comment: Thanks.Isee, it is by design. Security. So you have to paste something like "xjavascript:alert('hi')" and ask the user to remove the first char. Or ask the user to add it as a bookmarklet. I miss tainting. Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes, preventing pasting of code into the address bar is a security measure to make [self-XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS) harder. Same when you open the console for the first time and paste something.

Comment: For Chrome specifically, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82181

Answer (score 1):

However, this one works with Chrome and Firefox:

```
data:text/html,<script>alert('hi');</script>
```